Problem with finding $p_{ξ|ξ+η=z}(x)$.
The random variables $ξ$ and $η$ are independent and have an exponential distribution with density $p(x) = λe^{−λx}, x > 0$.
a)Find  $p_{ξ,ξ+η}(x, y)$ and $p_{ξ|ξ+η=z}(x)$.
b)$\mathbb{E}(ξ | ξ + η = z)$
c)$\mathbb{D}(ξ | ξ + η = z)$
What I did: calculated $p_{ξ,ξ+η}(x, y) = λ^2e^{−λy}$, $p_{ξ+η}(x) = λ^2xe^{−λx}$. Then, the problems appear: $p_{ξ|ξ+η=z}(x) = \frac{p_{ξ,ξ+η}(x, y)}{p_{ξ+η}(y)} = \frac{1}{y} $
Then, I use this conditional density for b) and integral does not converge. What's wrong?

Do not overlook the support of the distributions while writing the densities.

Note that for $a\ge 0$, $b\ge a$,
$$
\mathbb{P}(\xi\le a,\xi+\eta\ge b)=\int_0^a \mathbb{P}(\xi+\eta\ge b\mid \xi=x)  \lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx=\int_0^a \mathbb{P}(\eta\ge b-x\mid \xi=x) \lambda e^{-\lambda x}   dx
=\int_0^ae^{-\lambda(b-x)} \lambda e^{-\lambda x}   dx=a \lambda e^{-\lambda b}
$$
so the point density is
$$
p_{\xi,\xi+\eta}(a,b)=-\frac{\partial \mathbb{P}(\xi\le a,\xi+\eta\ge b)}{\partial a \partial b}=\lambda^2 e^{-\lambda b}.
$$
for $0\le a\le b$ and zero otherwise.
Hence the marginal density of the second argument is (as $0\le a\le b$ )
$$
p_{\xi+\eta}(b)=\int_0^b p_{\xi,\xi+\eta}(a,b)da =\lambda^2b e^{-\lambda b}.
$$
(which is $\Gamma(2,\lambda)$ distribution, by the way).
The conditional density thus is
$$
p_{\xi\mid \xi+\eta}(a,b)=\frac{p_{\xi,\xi+\eta}(a,b)}{p_{\xi+\eta}(a,b)}=\frac 1b
$$
for $a\in [0,b]$ (thus: uniform on $[0,b]$).
Now it only remains to compute the mean and the variance of this uniform distribution...
